# How to create github Repository and upload files from windows using batch command

Tags: git, batch-file, github

I want to to create Batch command file for GitHub.
by using that batch file 
can add new project file and commit, checkout.
also it have to delete files 
to create branch, 
create clone like this kind of facility

i am using following commands for GitHub but this commands have to run separately i need to combine all commands in one single batch file

```
# clone your own project
$ git clone dotfiles → git clone git://github.com/YOUR_USER/dotfiles.git
```

clone another project

```
$ git clone github/hub → git clone git://github.com/github/hub.git
```

open the current project's issues page

```
$ git browse -- issues → open https://github.com/github/hub/issues
```

open another project's wiki

```
$ git browse mojombo/jekyll wiki → open https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki
```

create a topic branch

```
$ git checkout -b feature ( making changes ... ) $ git commit -m "done with feature"
```

i am refering following link 
https://hub.github.com/
for github commands
i unable to create in single batch file for GitHub

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash file (even on Windows) called `git-xxx` (replace xx by a name representing your script overall goal)

Any script called git-xxx (no extension) can be called as `git xxx`, and will run in a git bash shell (even when called from a Windows CMD).

In that script, you need to make sure:

- you start with

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```
- your `$PATH` includes `<path/to/hub/>bin`

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/hub/bin
  ```
- your git is aliased to hub, as mentioned in [`hub.github.com`](https://hub.github.com)

  ```
  alias git=hub
  ```

Then you can use for instance `git browse` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

you can create .cmd batch file and call explicitly your git commands like

```
call git clone <repo_name>
call git checkout <branch_name>
call git push <origin_name>
etc.
```